# reactjs - Render single icon on hover for list item rendered from array

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hover

I have this sort of cards that are rendered from an array of objects.

**Parent Component:**

`[{foo: 'bar', baz: [{ name: string, path: string: '/'}]`

`state = {isHovering: false}`

```
handleMouseHover = () => {
    const { isHovering } = this.state;
    this.setState({ isHovering: !isHovering });
}
```

;

I'm passing down `handleMouseHover()` and `isHovering` down as props to a child component.

Resulting in something like this:

**Child Component**

```
<LinkContainer
  onMouseEnter={handleMouseHover}
  onMouseLeave={handleMouseHover}
  className="linkContainer"
>

 {isHovering && (
   <FontAwesomeIcon
     icon="copy"
     className="copyIcon"
     onClick={copyToClipboard}
   />
 )}
```

The result is 4 cards that contain 3 links. Each time I hover over a link I want the copy to clipboard icon to show. However, at the moment when I hover over any item it sets `isHovering` to `true` thus making all the icons visible. Ideally I just want the the icon for the link I hover over to become visible. Can someone help me to figure out a better solution or a refinement of my already written code.

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could keep an object in your state instead of a boolean, that has a key indicating if the object with that particular key as index is hovered or not.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    arr: [{ text: "foo" }, { text: "bar" }],
    isHovered: {}
  };

  handleMouseEnter = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { isHovered: { ...prevState.isHovered, [index]: true } };
    });
  };

  handleMouseLeave = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { isHovered: { ...prevState.isHovered, [index]: false } };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { arr, isHovered } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map((el, index) => (
          <Child
            onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(index)}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.handleMouseLeave(index)}
            text={el.text}
            isHovering={isHovered[index]}
            key={index}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Child({ onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave, text, isHovering }) {
  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
      {text} {isHovering && " (hovering!)"}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for your prompt and detailed response. I was trying to implement this. I don't have my map on the parent component, I actually have it on my child component. How would I deal with the `isHovered[index]` in that case.

Comment: @rowmna You're welcome. I'm not quite sure I understand. Maybe you could have a separate piece of state in every child component instead of a `isHovering` prop?

Comment: What do you mean? I think I have it almost working, and technically this is what I am looking for so kudos man! My parent component is a container (Class component) and it receives the props from a reducer, which gives me the payload in that structure. I pass the array as a whole down to my child component (stateless functional). In my child Component, I perform my loops and assignments. Hope that was a bit more clear

Comment: FYI I followed your advice to bring the state down to the child component and worked great. Again thanks for your input! @Tholle

Answer (score 0):

Create a property isHovered on item of an array dynamically and onMouseHover pass the item which you get in .map, now toggle the isHovered property. Should work now.

Answer (score 0):

There is simple solution with CSS.
Just add below CSS to the elements you want to show/hide on hover. By default put set CSS property

```css
{
  display: none
}
```

Element would be visible on mouse hover with below CSS.

```css
                '&:hover, &:focus-within': {
                  '.element-class': {
                    display: 'block',
                  },
                },
```