# reactjs - show div hover on loop .map

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

After setup a simple array, i'd like to on hover show a div i followed this aswer [reactjs - Render single icon on hover for list item rendered from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194663/reactjs-render-single-icon-on-hover-for-list-item-rendered-from-array)
but did not worked, i've tried to instead of use prevState use just state and so on.

So please, can anyone spare a hint on this?

```
  class Posts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      posts: [],

      isHovered: {}
    };
  }

  handleMouseEnter = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { isHovered: { ...prevState.isHovered, [index]: true } };
    });
  };

  handleMouseLeave = index => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return { isHovered: { ...prevState.isHovered, [index]: false } };
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { isHovering, isHovered } = this.state;

    const posts = this.state.posts.map((post, index) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div
            key={index}
            onMouseEnter={() => this.handleMouseEnter(index)}
            onMouseLeave={() => this.handleMouseLeave(index)}
            isHovering={isHovered[index]}
          >
            <div>
              <p>{post.title}</p>
              {this.state.isHovering && <div>Hovering right meow! </div>}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return <div>{posts}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: wherr is isHovering in your this.state?

Comment: This can be done with pure css

Comment: @sagar yes is in the this.state

Comment: @kinduser really? but event to add any link?

Comment: @zplack631 you dont need any events, just :hover in css. Provide me some example at stackblitz and I will show u

Comment: @kinduser 

it's ok the codesandbox?

Comment: Yeah codesandbox is fine